# dlib/python/macosx error: Expected numpy.ndarray of uint8

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, dlib

I tried to run the script

```
import dlib
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io


def detect_faces(image):

    # Create a face detector
    face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

    # Run detector and get bounding boxes of the faces on image.
    detected_faces = face_detector(image, 1)
    face_frames = [(x.left(), x.top(),
                    x.right(), x.bottom()) for x in detected_faces]

    return face_frames

# Load image
img_path = 'ig.jpeg'
image = io.imread(img_path)

# Detect faces
detected_faces = detect_faces(image)

# Crop faces and plot
for n, face_rect in enumerate(detected_faces):
    face = Image.fromarray(image).crop(face_rect)
    plt.subplot(1, len(detected_faces), n+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(face)
```

to detect faces in the image and crop faces.

Running this i get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "dlib_project.py", line 23, in <module>
detected_faces = detect_faces(image)
File "dlib_project.py", line 12, in detect_faces
detected_faces = face_detector(image)
RuntimeError: Expected numpy.ndarray of uint8
```

What does it mean and how do i solve it?

Comment: Try `print image.dtype(), type(image)` after `imread()`

Comment: Then i get TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable .

Comment: @swilda remove the parentheses after dtype

Comment: Getting the same Error as before: Expected numpy.ndarray of uint8

Comment: You can try make sure that `image` is `uint8` by putting `image=image.astype(np.uint8)` after `image=io.imread()`.

Comment: That did not work but i got a different workarount. [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `img = np.empty((100,100,1),dtype = np.uint16)
image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cvuint8 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image)`.
That works